# Converting code using hash to array

Tags: arrays, perl, maps

I am charged with making a Perl module more efficient. It takes log entries which are currently uniquely identified by date and server name and inserts them into our mysql database for later processing.

I've posted the original file and my attempt below. My code doesn't insert into the database. I'm sure its a simple array handling problem but not sure.

#### Original file

```
package UlsaSpectrumAnalyser;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use EnmServiceGroup;
use StatsDB;
use DBI;
use StatsTime;

sub new
{
    my $klass = shift;
    my $self = bless {}, $klass;
    return $self;
}

sub init($$$$)
{
    my ($self,$r_cliArgs,$r_incr,$dbh) = @_;
    $self->{'site'} = $r_cliArgs->{'site'};
    $self->{'siteId'} = $r_cliArgs->{'siteId'};
    $self->{'date'} = $r_cliArgs->{'date'};
    if ( exists $r_incr->{'UlsaSpectrumAnalyser'} )
    {
        $self->{'r_UlsaSpectrumAnalyser'} = $r_incr->{'UlsaSpectrumAnalyser'}->{'r_UlsaSpectrumAnalyser'};
    }
    else
    {
        $self->{'r_UlsaSpectrumAnalyser'} = {};
    }

    my @subscriptions = ();
    $self->{'serverMap'} = {};
    foreach my $service( "pmservice", "saservice" ) {
        my $r_serverMap = enmGetServiceGroupInstances($self->{'site'}, $self->{'date'},$service);
        while ( my ($server,$serverId) = each %{$r_serverMap} ) {
            push ( @subscriptions, {'server' => $server, 'prog' => 'JBOSS'} );
            $self->{'serverMap'}->{$server} = $serverId;
        }
    }
    return \@subscriptions;
}

sub handle($$$$$$$)
{
    my ($self,$timestamp,$host,$program,$severity,$message,$messageSize) = @_;
    if ( $::DEBUG > 9 ) { print "UlsaSpectrumAnalyser::handle got message from $host $program : $message\n"; }

    # Skip any warnings/errors
    if ( $severity ne 'info' ) {
        return;
    }

    my ($time)=$timestamp=~/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*/;
    my ($epochtime) = getDateTimeInMilliSeconds($timestamp);
    if ( $::DEBUG > 3 ) { print "UlsaSpectrumAnalyser::handle got message from $time $host $program : $message\n"; }

    #Sample Log
    #2017-09-08 14:55:36,028 INFO [com.X.Y.itpf.EVENT_LOGGER] (ajp-executor-threads - 18) [administrator, Spectrum Analyzer, DETAILED, #ULSA_COMPONENT_FFT, MeContext=lienb4003, Samples=65510; FileParsingTime(ms)=50; FastFourierTime(ms)=370; PostProcessingTime(ms)=3; #ChartScalingTime(ms)=1; TotalTime(ms)=424]

    if( $message =~ /.*ULSA_COMPONENT_FFT,\s+(\S+),\s+Samples=(\d+);\s+FileParsingTime\S+=(\d+);\s+FastFourierTime\S+=(\d+);\s+PostProcessingTime\S+=(\d+);\s+ChartScalingTime\S+=(\d+);\s+TotalTime\S+=(\d+)]/ ) {

       my $activity = $epochtime . '@@' . $host;  #TODO Handle array instead of hash. Working on separately
       my $serverid = $self->{'serverMap'}->{$host};
       $self->{'r_UlsaSpectrumAnalyser'}->{$activity} = {
               'time'                  => $time,
               'epochtime'             => $epochtime,
               'serverid'              => $serverid,
               'source'                => $1,
               'sample'                => $2,
               'file_parsing_time'     => $3,
               'fast_fourier_time'     => $4,
               'post_processing_time'  => $5,
               'chart_scaling_time'    => $6,
               'total_time'            => $7};
    }

}

sub handleExceeded($$$)
{
    my ($self, $host, $program) = @_;
}

sub done($$$)
{
    my ($self,$dbh,$r_incr) = @_;
    my $tmpDir = '/data/tmp';
    my $date=$self->{'date'};
    if (exists $ENV{'TMP_DIR'})
    {
        $tmpDir = $ENV{'TMP_DIR'};
    }
    my $bcpFileUlsaAnalyserLogs = "$tmpDir/ulsa_spectrum_analyser_logs.bcp";
    open (BCP, "> $bcpFileUlsaAnalyserLogs") or die "Failed to open $bcpFileUlsaAnalyserLogs";

    foreach my $activity (sort keys %{$self->{'r_UlsaSpectrumAnalyser'}}) {

       print BCP $self->{'siteId'} . "\t" .
           $self->{'r_UlsaSpectrumAnalyser'}->{$activity}->{'serverid'} . "\t" .
           $self->{'r_UlsaSpectrumAnalyser'}->{$activity}->{'time'} . "\t" .
           $self->{'r_UlsaSpiUectrumAnalyser'}->{$activity}->{'epochtime'} . "\t" .
           $self->{'r_UlsaSpectrumAnalyser'}->{$activity}->{'source'} . "\t" .
           $self->{'r_UlsaSpectrumAnalyser'}->{$activity}->{'sample'} . "\t" .
           $self->{'r_UlsaSpectrumAnalyser'}->{$activity}->{'file_parsing_time'} . "\t" .
           $self->{'r_UlsaSpectrumAnalyser'}->{$activity}->{'fast_fourier_time'} . "\t" .
           $self->{'r_UlsaSpectrumAnalyser'}->{$activity}->{'post_processing_time'} . "\t" .
           $self->{'r_UlsaSpectrumAnalyser'}->{$activity}->{'chart_scaling_time'} . "\t" .
           $self->{'r_UlsaSpectrumAnalyser'}->{$activity}->{'total_time'} . "\n";
    }
    close BCP;
    dbDo( $dbh, "DELETE FROM enm_ulsa_spectrum_analyser_logs  WHERE siteid = $self->{'siteId'} AND time BETWEEN '$date 00:00:00' AND '$date 23:59:59'" )
    or die "Failed to delete from enm_ulsa_spectrum_analyser_logs" . $dbh->errstr;

    dbDo( $dbh, "LOAD DATA INFILE '$bcpFileUlsaAnalyserLogs' INTO TABLE enm_ulsa_spectrum_analyser_logs" )
    or die "Failed to load new data from '$bcpFileUlsaAnalyserLogs' file to 'enm_ulsa_spectrum_analyser_logs' table" . $dbh->errstr;
    unlink($bcpFileUlsaAnalyserLogs);

    $r_incr->{'UlsaSpectrumAnalyser'} = {
                                 'r_UlsaSpectrumAnalyser' => $self->{'r_UlsaSpectrumAnalyser'}
                                 };
}

1;
```

#### My attempt

```
package UlsaSpectrumAnalyser;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use StatsDB;
use DBI;
use StatsTime;

sub new
{
    my $klass = shift;
    my $self = bless {}, $klass;
    return $self;
}

sub init($$$$)
{
    my ($self,$r_cliArgs,$r_incr,$dbh) = @_;
    $self->{'site'} = $r_cliArgs->{'site'};
    $self->{'siteId'} = $r_cliArgs->{'siteId'};
    $self->{'date'} = $r_cliArgs->{'date'};
    $self->{'r_instrDataEvent'}->{'ulsaStats'} = [];


    my @subscriptions = ();
    $self->{'serverMap'} = {};
    foreach my $service( "pmservice", "saservice" ) {
        my $r_serverMap = enmGetServiceGroupInstances($self->{'site'}, $self->{'date'},$service);
        while ( my ($server,$serverId) = each %{$r_serverMap} ) {
            push ( @subscriptions, {'server' => $server, 'prog' => 'JBOSS'} );
            $self->{'serverMap'}->{$server} = $serverId;
        }
    }
    return \@subscriptions;
}

sub handle($$$$$$$)
{
    my ($self,$timestamp,$host,$program,$severity,$message,$messageSize) = @_;
    if ( $::DEBUG > 9 ) { print "UlsaSpectrumAnalyser::handle got message from $host $program : $message\n"; }

    # Skip any warnings/errors
    if ( $severity ne 'info' ) {
        return;
    }

    my ($time)=$timestamp=~/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*/;
    my ($epochtime) = getDateTimeInMilliSeconds($timestamp);
    if ( $::DEBUG > 3 ) { print "UlsaSpectrumAnalyser::handle got message from $time $host $program : $message\n"; }

    #Sample Log
    #2017-09-08 14:55:36,028 INFO [com.X.y.itpf.EVENT_LOGGER] (ajp-executor-threads - 18) [administrator, Spectrum Analyzer, DETAILED, #ULSA_COMPONENT_FFT, MeContext=lienb4003, Samples=65510; FileParsingTime(ms)=50; FastFourierTime(ms)=370; PostProcessingTime(ms)=3; #ChartScalingTime(ms)=1; TotalTime(ms)=424]

    if( $message =~ /.*ULSA_COMPONENT_FFT,\s+(\S+),\s+Samples=(\d+);\s+FileParsingTime\S+=(\d+);\s+FastFourierTime\S+=(\d+);\s+PostProcessingTime\S+=(\d+);\s+ChartScalingTime\S+=(\d+);\s+TotalTime\S+=(\d+)]/ ) {
        my $serverid = $self->{'r_instrDataEvent'}->{'serverid'};
        my %event = (
            'time'                 => $time,
            'epochtime'            => $epochtime,
            'serverid'             => $serverid,
            'source'               => $1,
            'sample'               => $2,
            'file_parsing_time'    => $3,
            'fast_fourier_time'    => $4,
            'post_processing_time' => $5,
            'chart_scaling_time'   => $6,
            'total_time'           => $7
        );
        push @{$self->{'r_instrDataEvent'}->{'ulsaStats'}}, \%event;
    }
}

sub handleExceeded($$$)
{
    my ($self, $host, $program) = @_;
}

sub done($$$)
{
    my ($self,$dbh,$r_incr) = @_;

    my $bcpFileUlsaAnalyserLogs = getBcpFilename("enm_ulsa_spectrum_analyser_logs ");
    open (BCP, "> $bcpFileUlsaAnalyserLogs") or die "Failed to open $bcpFileUlsaAnalyserLogs";

    foreach my $activity (@{$self->{'r_instrDataEvent'}->{'ulsaStats'}}) {

       print BCP $self->{'siteId'} . "\t" .
           $activity->{'serverid'} . "\t" .
           $activity->{'time'} . "\t" .
           $activity->{'epochtime'} . "\t" .
           $activity->{'source'} . "\t" .
           $activity->{'sample'} . "\t" .
           $activity->{'file_parsing_time'} . "\t" .
           $activity->{'fast_fourier_time'} . "\t" .
           $activity->{'post_processing_time'} . "\t" .
           $activity->{'chart_scaling_time'} . "\t" .
           $activity->{'total_time'} . "\n";
    }
    close BCP;

    dbDo( $dbh, sprintf("DELETE FROM enm_ulsa_spectrum_analyser_logs  WHERE siteid = %d AND time BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'",
    $self->{'siteId'}, $self->{'r_instrDataEvent'}->{'ulsaStats'}->[0]->{'epochtime'},$self->{'r_instrDataEvent'}->{'ulsaStats'}->[$#{$self->{'r_instrDataEvent'}->{'ulsaStats'}}]->{'epochtime'}))
    or die "Failed to delete from enm_ulsa_spectrum_analyser_logs" . $dbh->errstr;#'

    dbDo( $dbh, "LOAD DATA INFILE '$bcpFileUlsaAnalyserLogs' INTO TABLE enm_ulsa_spectrum_analyser_logs" )
    or die "Failed to load new data from '$bcpFileUlsaAnalyserLogs' file to 'enm_ulsa_spectrum_analyser_logs' table" . $dbh->errstr;
}

1;
```

Comment: If you are asking for a code review, those questions are better posted on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: For a start you can remove the templates `($$$$$$$)` etc. from your subroutines. They don't do what you think they do and can be problematic, and they don't have any effect on methods anyway.

Comment: What database are you using? MySQL?

Comment: Have you *profiled* the code to see where the bottlenecks are? There's no point in just blindly changing things: you may be altering a section of code that is already fast, or you may actually slow things down. Take a look at [`Devel::NYTProf`](https://metacpan.org/release/Devel-NYTProf).

Answer (score 3):

I would say that the problem is your

```
my $bcpFileUlsaAnalyserLogs = getBcpFilename( "enm_ulsa_spectrum_analyser_logs " )
```

I doubt if the file name really has a space at the end!

I'm surprised that your `dbDo` or at least your

```
or die "Failed to load new data ... "
```

didn't catch this and report it. I don't like wrapping `DBI` code inside subroutines, especially when I can't see those subroutines.

Note also that you should be using *placeholders*

```
dbDo( $dbh, sprintf("DELETE FROM enm_ulsa_spectrum_analyser_logs  WHERE siteid = %d AND time BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'",
$self->{'siteId'}, $self->{'r_instrDataEvent'}->{'ulsaStats'}->[0]->{'epochtime'},$self->{'r_instrDataEvent'}->{'ulsaStats'}->[$#{$self->{'r_instrDataEvent'}->{'ulsaStats'}}]->{'epochtime'}))
or die "Failed to delete from enm_ulsa_spectrum_analyser_logs" . $dbh->errstr;#'
```

would be much better as

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(<<END_SQL);
DELETE FROM enm_ulsa_spectrum_analyser_logs
WHERE siteid = ? AND time BETWEEN ? AND ?
END_SQL

my $ulsa_stats = $self->{r_instrDataEvent}{ulsaStats};

$sth->execute(
    $self->{siteId},
    $ulsa_stats->[0]{epochtime}, 
    $ulsa_stats->[-1]{epochtime}
) or die "Failed to delete from enm_ulsa_spectrum_analyser_logs: " . $dbh->errstr;
```

Comment: Nah, works fine in the original file. The issue is where i use array instead of map.

Comment: The original file doesn't have a space at the end of the string.

Comment: I can't fathom how your new code relates to the old version. You need to create an *MCVE*: read [*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of just dumping two entire source files into the question. You should be publishing something that we can just copy and run ourselves to experience the same issue. And a "map" in Perl is a "hash"; `map` is a language word and using it any other way is confusing. In any case the new data