# Converting a hash to an array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I want to change this code from using a hash to an array, but I cannot find a good example to go on. Can anyone advise? My only inkling so far is to use `[ ]` in line 2.

```
my @subscriptions    = ();
$self->{'serverMap'} = {};

foreach my $service( "pmservice", "saservice" ) {

    my $r_serverMap = enmGetServiceGroupInstances($self->{'site'}, $self->{'date'}, $service);

    while ( my ($server, $serverId) = each %{$r_serverMap} ) {
        push ( @subscriptions, {'server' => $server, 'prog' => 'JBOSS'} );
        $self->{'serverMap'}->{$server} = $serverId;
    }
}

return \@subscriptions;
```

Comment: You can't just change a hash to an array without some more design work. Hashes use strings as keys whereas array indexes are integers. Whatever `$server` contains needs to be converted to an array index, and you will no longer have that string in the `$self` structure.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, these two assignments are unnecessary:

```
my @subscriptions    = ();
$self->{'serverMap'} = {};
```

The first does nothing and the second does nothing useful. When you declare an array with

```
my @subscriptions;
```

then it is created empty. Adding `= ()` to the definition achieves nothing.

And explicitly setting `$self->{'serverMap'}` to be an empty, anonymous hash isn't useful. When you start putting data into `$self->{'serverMap'}` you can decide what format that data should be in.

Secondly, you say that you want to replace a hash with an array. I assume that it's the hash that's currently stored in `$self->{'serverMap'}` that you want to replace. That's easy. Simply replace the line:

```
$self->{'serverMap'}->{$server} = $serverId;
```

with

```
push @{ $self->{'serverMap'}->{$server} }, $serverId;
```

In fact, let's get rid of all that unnecessary punctuation at the same time:

```
push @{ $self->{serverMap}{$server} }, $serverId;
```

And that's done. Originally, `$self->{'serverMap'}` contained a reference to a hash, now it contains a reference to an array.

Of course, that's only half the job. You now store the data as an array, but you also need to access the data as an array. Somewhere in your code, you'll be looking at the data in `$self->{'serverMap'}` - and now that needs to be changed too, otherwise your program will stop working.

Comment: See also this guy's previous question [*Converting code using hash to array*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51580447/converting-code-using-hash-to-array)

Comment: Always assign a value to your variables. Years ago, `mod_perl` use to reuse the data space without reinitializing it. Variables that were not assigned a value when declared, would use the value from the previous run.  This problem was fixed but who knows when a new idea comes along that will do the same thing. Get into the habit of programming defensively: always assign a value to your variables.

Comment: @shawnhcorey: It's been a long time and I've successfully forgotten most of what I knew about `mod_perl`, but didn't it only reuse package variables? It sees your program as a subroutine, so any lexical variables will be initialised correctly.

Comment: *"Always assign a value to your variables"* Nonsense. Defensive programming is reasonable, but this is just one example out of endless *"new ideas"* that you have solved by making your code unnecessarily more noisy. If you're using a *new thing* then you should get to know what problems it may bring with it. God forbid that every Perl program contains every hack to defend against every possible misbehaviour of its environment. In any case, this is clearly not a `mod_perl` program.

Comment: @Dave: *"didn't it only reuse package variables"* I think that's very likely. Just saving and reloading the memory image is very unlikely to restore lexical data on the stack frame because it is *mobile*, and I think Apache are cleverer than that. Restoring package variables seems like a good idea as long as you know it's happening.

Comment: @Borodin Apache wasn't but now it is. And this is not a "new" idea. It's more than 50 years old. And when it comes to programmers, out of sight is out of mind. Make everything explicit. "Noisy" is better than vague.

Comment: @shawn: So you are saying that Apache's *"thing"* is old and fixed, but we should code for it anyway, along with any *"new things"* that come along with the same bug, and which may be imposed on our program without us knowing? That's even worse. Stick to C.

Comment: @shawn: Do you also initialise all scalar variables to zero `0` or the empty string `""`? Now there's a puzzle: which should it be? And the world would end if `mod_perl` or something just as nasty set it to `undef`. What shall we do?

Answer (score 0):

same but looks shorter

```
my @subscriptions;
foreach my $service( "pmservice", "saservice" ) {
    $self->{serverMap} = enmGetServiceGroupInstances($self->{'site'}, $self->{'date'}, $service);

    push @subscriptions, map {
        +{ server => $_, prog => 'JBOSS' }
    } keys %{ $self->{'serverMap'} };
}
```